# Increase ComboBox with increments of 0.1 in vba

Tags: vba, numbers, userform

I have a Combobox in a Userform in word. I am trying to make it populate the revision number of the document. At the moment I can only get it to increase in full numbers 01, 02, 03, etc.

What I actually want it to do is increase in 0.1 increments, so - 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.

I've tried changing the formatting from "00" to "0.0" or "0.1" but that just continues the format and doesn't add 0.1 to each subsequent level.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sSaved As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim docType As String

On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To 20
        cboRev.AddItem Format(i, "00")
    Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimals are non-integer by definition. Declare `i` as double instead, and use `Step 0.1` to increment by a tenth:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sSaved As String
Dim i As Double
Dim docType As String

For i = 0 To 20.1 Step 0.1
    cboRev.AddItem Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(i, 1)
    'cboRev.AddItem Format(i, "0.0") 'alternative
Next i
```

Comment: Hi @TimStack - thanks for the comments above - however, when I update the code it says 'compile error - Method or data member not found' and highlights the .WorksheetFunction

Comment: I removed the application.Worksheetfunction with the my previous code of `Format(i, "0.0")` - now it works perfectly - thanks for you help!

Comment: Glad to see you got it working. Not sure why `Application.WorksheetFunction` won't work for you, as it's unaffected by local language settings.

Comment: Me neither, but the work around is fine in any case - thanks for  you help!!